# Django - set model's `CharField` primary key from processed `ImageField` data

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

This is maybe a poor way to ask this question, as I haven't yet tried anything since I'm not sure if it's even possible without a bunch of custom JS added to the admin.

Given a model such as:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField('SKU', max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    bar_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/barcodes')
```

I want the user to select an image which will be a photo of a product's barcode. The image then needs to be processed to scan for the barcode (I'm using `pyzbar`) and this value should be saved to the primary key field `sku`.

Since I can't save the model without a primary key, and I need to upload the image field to scan the barcode to discover the value to be used for the primary key, I'm thinking that the only way to do this would be to use some client side JS in the admin to upload the image to a temp location using a DRF endpoint (or similar), read the barcode and return that value to the client which could then set the value of `sku` with some basic javascript. Then the model can be saved and image uploaded (a second time).

**Is there a more straightforward way to do this in Django without adding my own client side JS to the admin and having to upload the photo twice?**

Comment: Is this a legacy database? I don't see a reason for this to be the primary key. It can be just a unique field.

Comment: @Melvyn I think you're right. Maybe it's just hard wired in my brain since the (very) old systems this is based on use SKU for the PK. I guess I could make it a unique field, give it a placeholder default value, then rewrite that value in my own pre_save method.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the primary key, which may complicate things - you can extend ImageField and see how it populates its width and height columns, then do the same for the `pyzbar` generated barcode. See the [update_dimension_fields](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L424) for inspriation:

> Update field's width and height fields, if defined.
>
> This method is hooked up to model's post_init signal to update
> dimensions after instantiating a model instance.  However, dimensions
> won't be updated if the dimensions fields are already populated.  This
> avoids unnecessary recalculation when loading an object from the
> database.
>
> Dimensions can be forced to update with force=True, which is how
> ImageFileDescriptor.**set** calls this method.

You would add a method to do the work for pyzbar and then [connect the signal](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L422) in the same way.